# Opening a Python thread in a new console window

Tags: python, windows, linux, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to make a program that will launch both a view window (console) and a command line. In the view window, it would show **constant** updates, while the command line window would use `raw_input()` to accept commands that affect the view window. I am thinking about using threads for this, but I have no idea how to launch a thread in a new console window. How would I do that?

Comment: Not sure if you can at all, but there are huge differences between platforms. Most importantly, the Windows console is different from UNIX terminals. What platform are you on?

Comment: I would like how to do it on both Windows and UNIX/Linux/Mac, and use sys.platform to be portable.

Comment: You can use multiple processes and named pipes? If you go with the multiple processes strategy, then there is alot of interprocess strategies. which platform do you use?

Comment: I would like to know how to do it on both Windows and UNIX/Linux/Mac.

Comment: What do you mean by "the multiple processes strategy"?

Comment: Where does the program that writes the updates come from. Can you control it?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it. I was intending for them both to be the same script, just different threads within it, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than use a console or terminal window, re-examine your problem.  What you are trying to do is create a GUI.  There are a number of cross-platform toolkits including Wx and Tkinter that have widgets to do exactly what you want.  A text box for output and an entry widget for reading keyboard input.  Plus you can wrap them in a nice frame with titles, help, open/save/close, etc.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with @stark a GUI is the way.

Purely for illustration here's a *not recommended non-GUI* way that shows how to do it using a thread, a subprocess, and a named pipe as IPC.

There are two scripts:

- `entry.py`: accept commands from a user, do something with the command, pass it to the named pipe given at the command-line:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import sys

  print 'entry console'
  with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as file:
      for command in iter(lambda: raw_input('>>> '), ''):
          print ''.join(reversed(command)) # do something with it
          print >>file, command # pass the command to view window
          file.flush()
  ```
- `view.py`: Launch the entry console, print constant updates in a thread, accept input from the named pipe and pass it to the updates thread:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import os
  import subprocess
  import sys
  import tempfile
  from Queue import Queue, Empty
  from threading import Thread

  def launch_entry_console(named_pipe):
      if os.name == 'nt': # or use sys.platform for more specific names
          console = ['cmd.exe', '/c'] # or something
      else:
          console = ['xterm', '-e'] # specify your favorite terminal
                                    # emulator here

      cmd = ['python', 'entry.py', named_pipe]
      return subprocess.Popen(console + cmd)

  def print_updates(queue):
      value = queue.get() # wait until value is available

      msg = ""
      while True:
          for c in "/-\|":
              minwidth = len(msg) # make sure previous output is overwritten
              msg = "\r%s %s" % (c, value)
              sys.stdout.write(msg.ljust(minwidth))
              sys.stdout.flush()

              try:
                  value = queue.get(timeout=.1) # update value
                  print
              except Empty:
                  pass

  print 'view console'
  # launch updates thread
  q = Queue(maxsize=1) # use queue to communicate with the thread
  t = Thread(target=print_updates, args=(q,))
  t.daemon = True # die with the program
  t.start()

  # create named pipe to communicate with the entry console
  dirname = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  named_pipe = os.path.join(dirname, 'named_pipe')
  os.mkfifo(named_pipe) #note: there should be an analog on Windows
  try:
      p = launch_entry_console(named_pipe)
      # accept input from the entry console
      with open(named_pipe) as file:
          for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
              # pass it to 'print_updates' thread
              q.put(line.strip()) # block until the value is retrieved
      p.wait()
  finally:
      os.unlink(named_pipe)
      os.rmdir(dirname)
  ```

To try it, run:

```
$ python view.py
```

Comment: I think I've understood the gist of your code. So to be sure, when you launched the subprocess `p = launch_entry_console(named_pipe)` and then started reading the file using `with open(named_pipe) as file`, is this reading done as `p` is running in the background? As in, I can already use this scheme if I want to terminate `p` when a certain text 'stop' is read with the open pipe.

Comment: Yes, `p` process is running while you are reading from the named pipe.

Comment: In Windows, you would use `console = ["cmd.exe", "/c", "start"]`. The `start` makes Windows open a new window. Also, I prefer to reference the COMSPEC environment variable and use capital letters, as in `console = [os.environ.get("COMSPEC", "CMD.EXE"), "/C", "START"]`, but that's just my style. Of course, I agree that a GUI would be a better solution than all of this.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED ANSWER:

```
import subprocess
command = "dir"
subprocess.run(["cmd.exe", "/c", "start", f"{command}"], timeout=15)
```

**"cmd.exe"** - if using Windows, Windows ONLY recognizes double quotes.
**"/c"** - says 'send the Return' after we send the 'dir'(for example) string.
**"start"** - says open new console window...even if debugging in Pycharm :)
**f"command"** - I use f-strings to send assemble strings Python3.6+
*(timeout optional)*