# Is there a way to simulate background console activity in Python?

Tags: python, string, windows, loops, console

I may have phrased the title oddly, but essentially I'm wanting the console to display:

'Loading...'

Where the dots loop, on the same line.

1. 'Loading'
2. 'Loading.'
3. 'Loading..'
4. 'Loading...'

My thought pattern would be to have four different strings, print one, clear the line, print the next, etc.

Is this possible to implement in Python? Perhaps using Windows console commands?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do, more generally? Why do you want to simulate console activity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manipulate cmd.exe from python, so that the output is shown in the cmd.exe window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472367/how-to-manipulate-cmd-exe-from-python-so-that-the-output-is-shown-in-the-cmd-ex)

Comment: using `\r` instead of `\n` you can move to the beginning of line and write again in the same place `print("Loading", end="\r")`, `print("Loading.", end="\r")`. OR simply use `print(".", end="")` to write dot after `Loading` without cleaning line.

Answer (score 0):

see this:
[Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar)

You can use a progress bar, which looks better ( taken from the link ) 
Code Example from the link:

```py
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    sleep(3)

 60%|██████    | 6/10 [00:18<00:12,  0.33 it/s]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `end="\r"` in `print()` then it will not go to next line but it will move to beginning of line - and then you can write again in the same line.

```
import time

print("Loading", end="\r")
time.sleep(1)
print("Loading.", end="\r")
time.sleep(1)
print("Loading..", end="\r")
time.sleep(1)
print("Loading...", end="\r")
time.sleep(1)

print()  # move to next line
```

And this can be useful when you have to change text in line.
But for adding dots it is simpler to use `end=""` to write in the same line

```
import itme

print("Loading", end="")

for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".", end="")

print()  # move to next line
```

This method is used by some modules to draw `progressbar`

---

**BTW:**

You can also `\r` and `end=""` to keep cursor at the end of line

```
import time

print("\rLoading", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\rLoading.", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\rLoading..", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\rLoading...", end="")
time.sleep(1)

print()  # move to next line
```

If new text is shorter than older text then you should write spaces at the end to remove previous text.

```
import time

print("\r....", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r... ", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r.. ", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r. ", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r ", end="")

print()  # move to next line
```

---

If you want to display other text at the same time then you may need to use module like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html), [urwind](http://urwid.org/), [npyscreen](http://www.npcole.com/npyscreen/) which can use special codes to move cursor in differen places in (some) terminals.